# How could wavefunction be the same and yet it has degenerate eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

In solid state physics, the schrodinger equation
$$H \psi_{\vec{k}} = E_{\vec{k}} \psi_{\vec{k}}$$
has solutions $\psi_{\vec{k}}(x)$. In the near free electron approximation, I was told that $$\psi_{\vec{k}+\vec{g}}(x)=\psi_{\vec{k}}(x)$$(exactly the same in real $x$, and no phase factor difference)

However, I was also told that this $\vec{g}$ induces a degeneracy in $n\vec{g}$ induces a degeneracy in energy, so that, $$\psi_{\vec{k}}(x)$$ has degeneracy of integer number in terms of $E_{\vec{k},n}$.

But how could that be?
How could $H \psi_{\vec{k}} = E_{\vec{k}} \psi_{\vec{k}}$ and $H \psi_{\vec{k}} = E_{\vec{k},n} \psi_{\vec{k}}$ both be true at the same time, where $E_{\vec{k},n}<E_{\vec{k},n+1}$?